# Angular 1.5: stopping a rootScope emit that has multiple listeners

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple controllers listening to a rootScope event. If I have logic to stop the propogation of the event in each controller, would the listeners in each controller still trigger?

I'm wondering if there's a race condition between stopping propogation of the event in one controller and the rest of the event listeners in the other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your hierarchy. If you are broadcasting, and you call `preventDefault()` inside your controller's listener, you can only guarantee that listeners defined in the scope of controllers that are children of that controller will have the `defaultPrevented` flag set to true. Siblings CANNOT be guaranteed to have the flag set, since DOM order determines which siblings will have the flag set. Other listeners in other controller scopes that are not descendants will not have the `defaultPrevented` flag set to true.

So, no, you don't have to worry about race conditions, but you must be aware of the scope hierarchy.

It should be noted that you can only `stopPropagation` for `$emit`-ed events, not `$broadcast`-ed events. Also, `$emit`-ed events move UP the scope hierarchy, so, if you are `$emit`-ing from `$rootScope`, only listeners on `$rootScope` will receive the message.

Further, creating listeners on `$rootScope` inside a controller is a very bad idea. The reason is that controllers are typically initialized and destroyed repeatedly. But listeners defined on `$rootScope` do not get destroyed with the controller. This means you will end up adding duplicate listeners to `$rootScope` everytime the controller is instantiated, resulting in several duplicate listeners being triggered.

From the docs for the `$on` method:

> `stopPropagation` - {function=}: calling stopPropagation function will
>   cancel further event propagation (available only for events that were
>   $emit-ed)
>   So you can use this if you are `$emit`-ing your event.

Otherwise, if you are `$broadcast`-ing...

> `preventDefault`- {function}: calling preventDefault sets
>   `defaultPrevented` flag to true. 
>   `defaultPrevented` - {boolean}: true if
>   preventDefault was called.